# cannot call member function without object

Tags: c++, function, object, member

There's the main file (where the error is occurring):

```
#include "classe_Segundo.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

CSegundo a;

int main (){

cout << "Equacao de Segundo Grau\n\n";
cin >> a;
CSegundo::delta(a);


return 0;   
}
```

And the error:

> Line 12: Cannot call member function `void CSegundo::delta(CSegundo)' without object

Why is that happenning even if I've created the object up there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to call it with `CSegundo::delta()` requires that `delta` be declared as a static member function. You need to call it like so:

```
a.delta();
```

You also do not need to pass the object as the first parameter, the compiler will do that for you.